# gcc error output not getting directed to file

Tags: python, linux, gcc, wxpython

I am having trouble finding out why a gcc process inside a python build (trying to build wxPython from source) is not outputting to a log file. I execute the python build like this:

python setup.py build > build.log

This setup script runs gcc inside of it. The messages are copious and scroll off the screen. That is why I have it directed to a log file. Unfortunately, nothing past the gcc command is being logged. In other words what is in the log file is this:

```
Preparing CORE...
Preparing STC...
[etc lots of other python-related messages]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing... [etc. very long gcc command]
```

and then nothing. The log just stops here. I know there is a lot more because when I run the same command at the terminal I get lots more stuff with a "gcc failed with exit code 1" at the end of it. However, since I can't see the gcc errors since they scroll off the screen I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` is writing to `stderr`. Chain it to `stdout` using `2>&1 > file`.
If you want to redirect only `stderr`, use `2> file`. Check the `man` of your shell for further information about redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the standard error output to build.log as well.
Redirection syntax is dependant on the shell that you use.

For plain `sh` and `bash`;

```
python setup.py build > build.log 2>&1
```

With `tcsh`:

```
python setup.py build >& build.log
```

Comment: If I do this I get several Python-related messages, then "invalid command name 'build.log' "